# Group/combine loggers in Mule

Tags: logging, mule, mule-studio, mule-component

Does anyone know if it's possible to combine multiple sequential loggers in Mule to make my flows look a little tidier in the GUI view? My reason for asking is that I often have flows with a series of loggers producing messages at different levels (DEBUG, INFO etc). Viewing this in the GUI makes my flows look cluttered.

```
<logger message="Foo" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
<logger message="Foo" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
<logger message="Foo" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

Was just wondering if there's a way around this so that when I have sequential loggers like above, there's only one element in my GUI view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group these `logger` elements in a `sub-flow` and `flow-ref`-it from the flows that need logging.